# Chip on the edge of the bathtub flange. Should I return it?

Tags: bathtub, damage, acrylic

Just got a Kohler acrylic bathtub delivered. Everything looks perfect except for this chip on the edge - https://imgur.com/a/R4xi8fm

[image]

It will be covered by the tile, but is there a chance it could cause a crack or any other issue in the long run? It's my second try already, the first bathtub had a major defect. I would not want to go through the return again if this is fairly normal and won't evolve in a crack over time

Comment: Looks like their quality control person got out sourced.  I think it is just cosmetic, but I am not a bathtub expert.  It should be returned for not being perfect, but it is up to you.  I would write a letter to the big rigs.

Comment: @Ruskes  Think that is more of the site being stupid.  I am glad to be over 18 to see a picture of a bathtub.   It does not even show the good bits.

Comment: I dont think it will progress either

Comment: What are the dimensions of the chip? And the tile thickness.  It looks like similar in size to the thickness of tile+adhesive, too close for comfort in terms of getting everything sealed and even.  But without numbers it's a guess

Comment: @ChrisH it's about 1/4" by 1/2" - https://imgur.com/a/AMAsphW

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as the chip will be covered by the tile/sealant by at least 3mm or 4mm (5/32nds of those inches things?) you should be good to go. Generally chips don't 'spread' and the underneath material is also water resistant.

Comment: My worry was that you're asking more of the sealant in that spot - with thin tiles you won't get that overlap and you might need to build it up. The bath is made of waterproof materials but the wall probably isn't

Comment: I tend to agree that this is probably harmless. I would still make the vendor take it back and deliver an undamaged unit, if I could afford the delay.

Comment: Thank you for the answers. My porcelain tile is 1/2 in thick. I decided to keep the tub since Homedepot offered $150 compensation for the imperfection